# Memory allocation unsuccessful when Dll injecting into notepad

Tags: windows, winapi

I am trying to inject a dll I've made into note pad.
I've written the following code where I open a process of notepad and inject it with my dll.
Yet, for some reason, my virtualalloc fails.
Would really appreciate some help on the matter.
Code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char dllPath[125];
    DWORD pathLen = GetFullPathNameA("MagshimimFinalProject.dll" ,160 , dllPath, NULL);
    PVOID addrLoadLibrary = (PVOID)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("notepad.exe"), "LoadLibraryA"); // maybee we need text instead of the dllpath
    HANDLE proc = OpenProcess("PROCESS_CREATE_PROCESS",FALSE, "6340");
    PVOID memAddr = (PVOID)VirtualAllocEx(proc, NULL,pathLen,MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    if (NULL == memAddr)
    {
        printf("Couldn't allocate memory");
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        return 0;
    }
    HANDLE hRemote = CreateRemoteThread(proc,NULL,0,memAddr, NULL,0,NULL );
    if (NULL == hRemote)
    {
        printf("Couldn't create thread");
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        return 0;
    }
    WaitForSingleObject(hRemote, INFINITE);
    BOOL check = CloseHandle(hRemote);
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried looking up all of the functions and making sure they are all getting the right variables, and looking up tutorials on the matter on youtube, but to no avail.
Edit - as the first comment suggested, I've used the debugger to look at each and every line, and when I checked addrLoadLibrary its value was: "identifier "addrLoadLibrary" is undefined" for some reason. any clue why that is?
Edit 2 - firstly, I was checking its value after the line has been completed (value of addrloadlibrary). Secondly, as someone has mentioned, proc is actually the problem for some reason, as its always NULL. Still trying to figure out why is it not working
edit 3 - fixed the problem with proc by removing the quotation marks like some guy in the comments was telling me (sorry for not remembering name, I'm very bad at that.) Now all thats left to figure out is why is addrLoadLibrary undefined even after line
edit 4 - re-read the documentation of the function "getModuleHandle" and relized it should get the dllpath variable. hopefully im not wrong because im not a native english speaker and documentations are especially tough for me to understand.

Comment: ***"identifier "addrLoadLibrary" is undefined" for some reason. any clue why that is?*** I think you are checking the value before the line was executed.

Comment: `HANDLE proc = OpenProcess("PROCESS_CREATE_PROCESS",FALSE, "6340");` was the value of the `proc` valid?

Comment: Looks like you are calling that function  wrongly according to the documentation: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess) the first and third parameters are supposed to be `DWORD` but you are passing a string literal.

Comment: ***looking up tutorials on the matter on youtube*** I would advise against that. Read the documentation instead.

Comment: `char dllPath[125];` then `DWORD pathLen = GetFullPathNameA("MagshimimFinalProject.dll" ,160 , dllPath, NULL);` is also a bug. You allocate space for 125 characters then lie to the function that you allocated 160.

Comment: My comment advising you to add error checking and debug your program was removed. Not sure what we're doing here if the single most important advice that can be given to this asker is removed.

Comment: I have already told you why proc is null. You used invalid parameters to OpenProcess() it does not use string literals. It uses DWORD paramaters. Get rid of the quotes on that call.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yeah I noticed it disappeared, but I've tried looking for error. All I've found this far is that proc is always null, for some reason addrLoadLibrary is undefined even after the line is complete. Still working on it tho so there is hope!

Comment: `HANDLE proc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_CREATE_PROCESS,FALSE, 6340);` and make sure 6340 is the correct process id. Your code should check the return value and print an error message and / or exit on failure.

Comment: It's unclear why you want a pointer to the load library function from the windows API anyways. That is not needed for anything you do below. You probably just want to delete this line completely: `PVOID addrLoadLibrary = (PVOID)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("notepad.exe"), "LoadLibraryA"); // maybee we need text instead of the dllpath`

Comment: Why haven't you implemented error checking yet?

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of things wrong with this code. Most of the API calls are just plain incorrect. You are not doing very much error checking. You are not copying the DLL path into the memory you allocate before creating the remote thread.

Try something more like this instead:

```c
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char dllPath[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD pathLen = GetFullPathNameA("MagshimimFinalProject.dll", MAX_PATH, dllPath, NULL);
    if (!pathLen) {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        printf("Couldn't get DLL path. Error: %u", err);
        return 0;
    }
    PVOID addrLoadLibrary = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
    // TODO: use CreateToolhelp32Snapshot() or EnumProcesses() to find the correct process ID...
    DWORD procID = 6340;
    HANDLE proc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, procID);
    if (!proc) {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        printf("Couldn't open process. Error: %u", err);
        return 0;
    }
    PVOID memAddr = VirtualAllocEx(proc, NULL, pathLen+1, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (!memAddr) {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        CloseHandle(proc);
        printf("Couldn't allocate memory. Error: %u", err);
        return 0;
    }
    if (!WriteProcessMemory(proc, memAddr, dllPath, pathLen+1, NULL)) {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        VirtualFreeEx(proc, memAddr, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(proc);
        printf("Couldn't write to memory. Error: %u", err);
        return 0;
    } 
    HANDLE hRemote = CreateRemoteThread(proc, NULL, 0, addrLoadLibrary, memAddr, 0, NULL);
    if (!hRemote) {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        VirtualFreeEx(proc, memAddr, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(proc);
        printf("Couldn't create thread. Error: %u", err);
        return 0;
    }
    WaitForSingleObject(hRemote, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(hRemote);
    VirtualFreeEx(proc, memAddr, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    CloseHandle(proc);
    return 0;
}
```